# StatusBarColor with a subtle gradient like in the previews? (Android 5.0)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm setting this in my code:

```
<style name="custom_theme" parent="android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar">
     <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

which works and makes it transparent, but in the [Customizing the Status Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#StatusBar) bit on the Material Design page it says it should produce a subtle gradient like in the preview pics? Am I missing something here? I'm running Android 5.0 on the AVD emulator, if that makes a difference.

Comment: There's no gradient in the previews, unless you mean the faux reflection in the device mock-up. There is no status bar gradient in Material.

Comment: This is what I'm referring to: "For example, if you want to show the status bar transparently over a photo, with a subtle dark gradient to ensure the white status icons are visible. To do so, set the android:statusBarColor attribute to @android:color/transparent and adjust the window flags as required."

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You need to draw the gradient yourself in the status bar inset area. See [Make Content Appear Behind the Status Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#behind) on the developer site.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! Do you happen to know if the fullscreen flag there works for the navigation bar also? If I set it to transparent will the background of the layout show through it, for example? Thanks again!

Comment: These APIs were introduced in KitKat, not Lollipop. Maybe you should look at the KitKat release documentation.